# All Google Cloud SQL instances are getting suspended

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm pretty new to Cloud SQL and decided to use it for a course project. I'm trying to use Cloud SQL but each time I create a new instance (second generation type) it ends up getting suspended and I can no longer access it through the Google Cloud Platform console, mysql, etc.

It seems that most of the time, instances get suspended due to billing issues but I've enabled the billing option in the console and all of my information is correct.

The instance will work and be accessible for a few minutes after creation but soon thereafter it moves to this 'Suspended' state.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Comment: Visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues#suspended) for a number of reasons why Google Cloud SQL may suspend an instance. Also, as Vadim mentioned you can open ticket with Google Cloud Billing team via this [form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing).

Answer (score -1):

You can visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues#suspended) for a number of reasons why Google Cloud SQL may suspend an instance. Also, as Vadim mentioned you can open ticket with Google Cloud Billing team via this [form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing).